# Pop up and enlarge image on selected image

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have this php code which is working fine. I would like somehow, instead of redirecting to the actual link of the image, to pop up a window(Im using bootstrap, so I would guess modal?) and display the image. So that, it will never leave the actual index.php page. Could give me some ideas about how to do that?

```
<?php
        $dirname = "images/";
        $images = scandir($dirname);
        rsort($images);
        $ignore = array(".", "..");
        foreach($images as $curimg){
            if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
                echo "<li><a class='thumbnail' href=\"$dirname$curimg\"><img src='img.php?src=$dirname$curimg&w=300&zc=1' alt='' /></a></li>\n ";
            }
        }               
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a lightbox. I think there used to be a package called lightbox, though I just recently used "prettyPhoto" and it worked perfect for my needs. You generate your thumbnail of the image, and attach the tags necessary for prettyPhoto to work. Boom, you click the thumbnail and a lightbox pops up showing the full size image. You can have galleries where the user can click the arrows to scroll through the pictures in the set. You can add facebook buttons. Whatever you want.

Original repo: https://github.com/scaron/prettyphoto

I think this is their website, but has the doc, and some examples too: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Comment: Im currently using that one for my project, but the problem is that I need to display the gallery page within an i frame. On normal size computers works fine, but on mobile devices like iPad. The pop picture it wont centered on the screen and I have to scroll the page till i find it. I dont know if you know what I mean. Thats why im trying to implement something from the scratch.

Comment: For me, an iframe is a last resort. I don't think I have used an iframe for over 5+ years. I really hate them, and prefer any other solution other than an iframe. I think there are better ways than an iframe. Using another lightbox script in the past, it had the ability to add pages to the popup. I could have a popup come up and show a PDF, or an iframe, or another website, right in my lightbox.  -- Though maybe on the lightbox you can have a {TEMPLATE} tag to tell jquery to replace it with the html you need. I would use jquery before an iframe